# infinite loop when fetching from firestore in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

This is my context provider component in React

```
export const DataContext = createContext();

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const q = query(
                    collection(db, "xyzCollection"),
                    where("Status", "==", "Active")
                );
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                let list = [];
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    list.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
                });
                setClients(list);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("could not fetch clients", err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [clients]);

    const dataInfo = {
        clients,
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <DataContext.Provider value={dataInfo}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};
export default DataProvider;
```

Including this  snippet in my component  creates an infinite loop where it keeps fetching data from firestore . Is their a better way to fetch data ?

tldr: useEffect executes infinite time

Comment: Its because you setClients(list) in that function. The value of client changes which causes useEffect to run again since you have client in your deps.

Comment: @SLNM thanks for this . I already have a useEffect hook that fetches data from another collection with empty dependency array , i dont think it is a good practice to have to useEffect hooks with empty dependency array. Is their a method ?